# Dealing with keyboard on mobile devices in prototyping tools such as Figma

Tags: iphone, viewport, onscreen-keyboard

I am trying to build an app and I'm starting with prototyping it, but I am not a professional UX & UI designers (I'm a software developer), so apologies if my question seems silly.

I am starting in the mobile view.

[image: app homepage]

The above is built in Figma. That is the **iPhone SE** frame in Figma which is 320px by 568px (according to Figma at least).

When the user focus on the search, the **iOS keyboard will pull up** and take a lot of space.

How am I, as someone who is trying to prototype the app supposed to know how much space (in pixels) the iOS keyboard takes?

Figma as a tool doesn't tell me, and when I search for iPhone SE viewport, none of the sites that come up tell me either.

Comment: Not entirely sure but there are as many mobile phones as keyboard apps. Some with suggested words and other features taking up more space. My guess would be they can't. However you could find an ios components UI kit and add the keyboard yourself to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size the native keyboard on an iPhone SE in portrait orientation is **216px**. Here's a mockup of it in the device:

[image: iPhone SE Keyboard]